# bash for loop sed mind trouble

Tags: bash, loops, sed, nic

I'd like to do a sed to a multiple ifcg-file, but 'eth$i' do not increment, there is eth0 is in every files.
My goal is to have inside eno1 eth0, inside enps0  eth1 ...

Thanks a lot If anyone can help

```
ls test
eno1  enps0  enps1  enps2  enps3  lo
```

```
cat test/eno1
name=eno1
device=eno1
```

```
for NAME in $(ls test/ | grep -v lo | sort)
do
        for (( i=0; i<$(ls test/ | grep -v lo | wc -l); i++ ))
        do
            sed -i "s/${NAME}/eth${i}/g" test/$NAME
        done
done
```

In the final I'd like to have

```
cat test/eno1
name=eth0
device=eth0
```

```
cat test/enps0  
name=eth1
device=eth1
```

```
cat test/enps1   
name=eth2
device=eth2
```

...

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: In the first iteration of the outer loop, NAME is set to `eno1`. Then you perform for the file `eno1` 5 iterations in the inner loop, with `i` bound to 0..4. In the first inner iteration, you replace inside the file `eno1`  the string `eno1` by `eth0`. On the next iteration (`i` equals 1), you try to replace every `eno1` by `eth1`, but there is no `eno1` anymore in this file. Hence it sticks to `eth0`. You can easily verify this by doing a `cat test/$NAME` after the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
i=0                                             # initialize the variable i
for f in test/*; do                             # loop over the files in the directory test/
                                                # note that you don't need to "sort" here
    name=${f##*/}                               # extract the basename of the file
    if [[ -f $f && $name != "lo" ]]; then       # if "$f" is a regular file and not "lo"
         sed -i "s/$name/eth${i}/" "$f"         # substitute the device name
         (( i++ ))                              # increment the value of i
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you store the files in an array, you can use the array index for the interface.

```
cd test
files=( e* )
for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "name=eth%s\ndevice=eth%s\n" $i $i > "${files[i]}"
done
```